# Plugin echos text from shortcode function in gutenberg page editor

Tags: plugins, shortcode, query, block-editor

I'm creating a plugin to load custom posts by custom taxonomy (restaurant menu plugin).. I'm calling the main function (holds everything) by the add_action hook on 'init' and inside it I have another function that is using the new Wp_query to load these custom posts content.

I add a shortcode to this function and placed it in the gutenberg widget editor. The content  is loading perfectly in the main restaurant menu page, however I can also see the echos in the gutenberg editor of the menu page....

What am I doing wrong?

```
    function benito_generate_menu_posts() {

    $args2 = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'item_type',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    );

    $types = get_categories($args2);

    function load_post_with_tax($tax_type) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'menu',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'item_type',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $tax_type,
                )
            )
        );

        $query1 = new WP_query ( $args );
        while($query1->have_posts()) : $query1->the_post();
        echo '<div class="menu-thumb">';
            the_post_thumbnail( );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="menu-title">';
            the_title( );
            echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="menu-content">';
            the_content( );
        echo '</div>';

        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query
    }


    foreach($types as $type) { 
         load_post_with_tax($type);
    } 





}
add_shortcode( 'get_menu_items' , 'benito_generate_menu_posts' );
```

Comment: Does your shortcode `return` it’s content? Shortcodes can’t directly produce output.

Comment: mmm no it has a foreach loop at the end with contains a function call in itself..         `foreach($types as $type) { 
             load_post_with_tax($type);
        }`

Comment: and what does `load_post_with_tax` do?

Comment: edit my post with the code :)

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: I did... I don't know what you mean exactly.. The echos are returning...but also returning in the editor page...

Comment: [Look at the examples here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). No `echo`, only a single `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Milo noticed, shortcodes should `return` content instead of `echo`ing it. So change

```
while($query1->have_posts()) : $query1->the_post();
echo '<div class="menu-thumb">';
    the_post_thumbnail( );
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="menu-title">';
    the_title( );
    echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="menu-content">';
    the_content( );
echo '</div>';

endwhile;
```

to

```
   while($query1->have_posts()) : $query1->the_post();
        $div = '<div class="menu-thumb">';
        $div .= get_the_post_thumbnail( );
        $div .= '</div>';
        $div .= '<div class="menu-title">';
        $div .= get_the_title( );
        $div .= '</div>';
        $div .= '<div class="menu-content">';
        $div .= get_the_content( );
        $div .= '</div>';
        return $div;
   endwhile;
```

(replace `echo` with `return` and also anywhere there is a `the_something()` replace it with `get_the_something()` so that at the very end, it `return`s the whole chunk of output.)

Comment: Since it worked, could you please accept the answer so the community has it marked? :)

Comment: sorry about that... I just voted up...Im kind of new to this...anyway, accepted :)